# How to generate Signature Method OAuth1

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, signature

i want build project with `OAuth1` and i found sign request like this :

```
Authorization:
    OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog",
          oauth_nonce="kYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg",
          oauth_signature="tnnArxj06cWHq44gCs1OSKk%2FjLY%3D",
          oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
          oauth_timestamp="1318622958",
          oauth_token="370773112-GmHxMAgYyLbNEtIKZeRNFsMKPR9EyMZeS9weJAEb",
          oauth_version="1.0"
```

but, how i can got

> oauth_signature, oauth_nonce, oauth_timestamp ?

how to make it without Postman ?

Answer (score 0):

Use library OAuthSwiftAlamofire

No need to create **oauth_signature**, **oauth_nonce** and **oauth_timestamp** manually.Check the sample code

```
let oauthswift = self.getAuth1Object()
oauthswift.client.credential.oauthToken = kAuthToken
oauthswift.client.credential.oauthTokenSecret = kAuthTokenSecret
let sessionManager = SessionManager.default
sessionManager.adapter = OAuthSwiftRequestAdapter(oauthswift)
let api =  sessionManager.request(strURL,method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default,headers: ["Content-Type" :"application/json"])
```

And this is your **getAuth1Object()**

```
func getAuth1Object() -> OAuth1Swift {
        let oauthswift = OAuth1Swift(
            consumerKey:   "put your consumer key here",
            consumerSecret: "put your consumer secret here",
            requestTokenUrl: "",
            authorizeUrl:    "",
            accessTokenUrl:  ""
        )
        return oauthswift
    }
```